# ASP NET MVC Web deploy (publish) preview with node js - error log

Tags: asp.net, node.js, visual-studio, publish, webdeploy

I have an MVC project with node js build commands.
When I'm making publish I just invoke two commands before deploy:

```
npm install
npm run build-test
```

The `build test` runs a `es-lint` before bundle all of the files and sometimes it indicates that there are errors like `missing semi-colon` and the bundle process fails.

The Preview functionality fails and there is an option to see the details. It opens the `__VSDeploymentFailure__.txt` but show only that the command fails.

[image]

Is there a way to see full log error when using `Preview` option before real publish?

Of course when try to publish it fails again but with details errors from npm:

> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 2
>   npm ERR! app.project@1.0.0 build-test: `webpack --config  webpack.config.test.js`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 2
>   npm ERR! Failed at the app.project@1.0.0 build-test script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Answer (score 0):

`npm` command install packages that are part of `package.json` with given version of package. In `scripts` inside `package.json`, we can run other commands like where you have provided `npm run build-test`.

You have not given package.json so from error I am assuming your command corresponding to `npm run build-test` is `webpack --config  webpack.config.test.js` which is actually getting error.

npm actually mask actual error to debug you should replace

`webpack --config  webpack.config.test.js`

with

`webpack --config webpack.config.test.js --display-error-details`

then try running either  `npm run build-test`

OR directly for debugging you can try `webpack --config webpack.config.test.js --display-error-details` with out any changes in package.json. If you are running directly webpack make sure `webpack` is installed globally like `npm install -g webpack`.

Comment: Hi, I know from where the bug comes (es-lint warnings) and if I use `Publish` instead of `Preview` It shows the full log. But my question is how to see full log if I user `Preview`.

Comment: try adding `--display-error-details` in webpack command like `webpack --config webpack.config.test.js --display-error-details`

Comment: In package.json added `"build-test": "webpack --config webpack.config.test.js --display-error-details"` and still shows `The command "npm run build-test" exited with code 2.`   The problem I think is somewhere in Visual Stuidio configurations